# Filter entries with segments and params based on categories and fields

Tags: entries, search, filter, segments, params

I'm working on a webshop with an advanced filter / search with multiple categories, entry types and fields and sorting options.

**Schematic URL**
site.com/template/entry.type/category/?size=category OR category&color=category AND category&checkbox=yes

**Real world example**
site.com/shop/woman/jeans/?size=s,m&color=blue,red&delivery=yes

What is the best way to show the entries? With search or relatedTo?

**This is what I have so far:**

```
{% if craft.request.getSegment('3') is not null %}
    {% set kind_slug = craft.request.getSegment('3') %}

    {% set categoryParams = {
        group: 'kind',
        slug: kind_slug
    } %}

{% else %}
    {% set categoryParams = {
       all kinds
    } %}
{% endif %}

{% set kind = craft.categories(categoryParams).first() %}
{% set size = craft.request.getParam('size') %} #}
{% set color = craft.request.getParam('color') %} #}

{% set params = {
    section: 'product',
    type: craft.request.getSegment(2),
    relatedTo: kind AND size AND color
} %}

{% for entry in craft.entries(params).find() %}
    {{ entry.title }}   
{% endfor %}
```

I want the same functionality as this EE plugin: 
http://www.ralphmedia.co.uk/reefine/demo_basic

Comment: Johannes, could you split this question into smaller parts please?

Comment: Is this better? Can't get is smaller.

Comment: @JohannesLamers try rephrasing the question? Are you asking if it possible to search Craft entries using Faceted search? [Faceted Search, Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faceted_search) I would love to know the answer to this as well but I think you are running into an issue because the question is too broad... I would pick search as your method and then ask a question that is directed along those lines. I am not a SE expert though so I could be wrong : )